# Packages to run Firefox window on a server?

Tags: server, 16.04, desktop-environments, remote-desktop

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 and to test something I want to use firefox on the machine remotely with:

```
firefox -no-remote
```

When I try it I get back

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Should I `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or is there a way to do it without, or with a smaller package?

I don't want to just proxy through either I want to view my server's localhost.

*Update:*

tried connecting with `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y` and got the same error.

Comment: Any -desktop would be an overkill. [Xubuntu-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xubuntu-core) might be a better deal, but still way too much.

Comment: Openbox would be a lightweight, albeit *very* minimal GUI.

Comment: Firefox should still open after this message.

Comment: It didn't open in my case. Openbox looks like what I need. I installed but can't start it. Anyone able to provide instructions on how to get openbox working with 16.04?

Comment: Actually I wonder if there are more errors shown, because usually if you don't set DISPLAY properly, it should complain "could not open display". Now back to the solution; If you are using Linux GUI, you can easily redirect the display to your local X server; so you don't need any windows manager on the server; "ssh -Y" to this server, install firefox, then type "firefox", it can be displayed on your local X session. If you are using windows, you can use cygwin/X.

Comment: For starting Openbox, look at create a `~/.xinitrc` file with `exec openbox-session` in it. Now type `startx` at the TTY.

Comment: @DavidFoerster that was easy. Do you want to post it as an answer and I will accept with bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package `libcanberra-gtk3-module` (`libcanberra-gtk-module` for older Firefox versions built without GTK 3 support) to get rid of this error. It doesn't require a desktop environment, just some libraries for ALSA, GTK, and X11 support.

I find it weird that the `firefox` package doesn't depend on that if Firefox cannot run without it. I submitted a [bug report to Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1588810) to investigate the issue further.

Comment: My problem was that I started by trying to install 'libcanberra-gtk-module'  as that was what was mentioned in the error. The '3' made all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

- Ubuntu server is not bundled with any graphical desktop environment and due to that, you cannot run traditional GUI apps, which in this case, is firefox
- If you don't mind sacrificing some resources, installing a desktop environment would be suitable. *LXDE* has an extremely low memory footprint (it is also the default DE for RaspberryPi and hence the low memory claim has been validated)
- If you only want to perform basic browsing and searching operations,
  you can use *Links2* or *Lynx*.

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
>
> Update:
> tried connecting with ssh -X and ssh -Y and got the same error.

It still won't run since the GTK modules are absent on your server itself. It cannot render and send it over SSH if it does not have any modules in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Simply installing `libcanberra-gtk3-module` fixed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

`libcanberra-gtk-module` if using an old browser without gtk3 support.

(credit to @David Foerster who suggested this in comments)

---

If you're going to use other GUI applications you might want to consider `LXDE` instead as suggested in Anonymint's answer.

Comment: I don't think the error is relevant to this problem; When I "ssh -Y" to my lxc container which bases on ubuntu cloud image(of coz it does not include X server, its rootfs is less than 150M), after installing firefox by "sudo apt install firefox"(104 packages, 76.2M), this should automatically pull enough dependencies to render and redirect. When running "firefox", it prints two lines of "canberra-gtk-module" errors, browser UI is still shown as @adonis mentions. If installing "lubuntu-desktop"(776 packages, 373M).

Comment: Better install `lubuntu-core` which has less dependencies and if you want even less dependencies then install `lxde-core` (it won't contain any gui applications to manage for example users, time, startup applications, archive files etc.). See the difference in those links: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lxde-core, http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lubuntu-core.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu server doesn't come with a GUI, therefore you can't run GUI-demanding programs like Firefox. You're going to have to install Ubuntu desktop.

At the terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was an easy way to get it working without making any changes to the existing system. I've since found that using Xubuntu in combination with X2Go gives the best results when you want to use Ubuntu for your server while having a good remote desktop experience.

X2Go can also be used with Lubuntu and other distros but it's not compatible with unity and thus not compatible with stock Ubuntu (also light weight is just better in this situation).

I have a 16.04 Docker image you can use to give it a try [here](https://github.com/kirkins/DockerX2go).